# 16gb seems not enough to parse 1gb JSON in Kotlin, can I optimize my code?

Tags: performance, kotlin, parsing, heap-memory

I have an 1gb json file which I would like to parse in Kotlin. I am using the jacksonObjectMapper for this.

```
val mapper = jacksonObjectMapper().disable(DeserializationFeature.FAIL_ON_UNKNOWN_PROPERTIES)
    val b : List<Profile> = mapper.readValue(File("$path/$inputFile2").readText())
```

Heap space was not sufficient at 13gb, so I increased to 16gb (even though my Windows 10 Laptop has only 16gb RAM, so I didn't expect this to work) and IntelliJ was not reacting anymore after waiting 15min for the parsing to finish. It didn't alert for "not enough heap space" in that setting anymore, though..

Is there something I can change in my code to get this to work on my 16gb RAM machine? Maybe run it as a jar in CMD?

Isn't it strange that a 1gb file can take up so much space?

Comment: The memory usage totally depends on your JSON content and structure. What kind of JSON data are you dealing with? Do you need to load the entire JSON file into memory in order to parse it? Do you need to parse everything at once and have the resulting data in memory all at once? Or could you instead use a streaming parser and object after object, use it, and then dispose it before dealing with the next object. That way you'll never use more than a few MB of memory depending on the JSON structure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your comment @fluidsonic.

The json is a list of 400 000 Objects.

What I did now was to organize the json file in a way so that each line contained 1 object. I was then doing the following:

```
File("$path/$inputFile2").readLines().forEach { 
    val x: Profile = mapper.readValue(it) 
    // + logic 
}
```

I believe this could have been done differently, but it worked like charm.